# Can I get source code from PyInstaller generated package?

Tags: pyinstaller

Seems the PyInstaller put all the python script into the executable file, and when run this file, it start PyInstaller bootloader first, then prepare a temp python environment add run the scripts.

So I wonder whether my source code are safe. Can I get the source code from the package when running the executable file?

Answer (score 2):

PyInstaller includes the byte compiled (.pyc) files of your program but not the original source (.py) files. You don't even need to run the executable to get the .pyc files. There are more or less working Python decompilers that turn compiled byte code (.pyc) into equivalent source code (.py).

You need to assess whether this protection is good enough for your purposes. However as a friendly suggestion, I recommend first inventing/writing something that people will want to copy before worrying about how to protect it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And how can I get the .pyc files?